# Have created a Custom Formula Field Country which should be able to fetch Country Name from the Address standard field on Lead Object

Tags: formula-field, sales-cloud, web2lead

Hello SFDC Experts and Community People,
Thanks for all your help so far to help me with the JS code which was inserted in Web2Lead HTML form code to obtain Lead's country info. However as the business requirement is to update the Country field on Lead object I  have created a **custom Formula field called Country on Lead object** which should be able to fetch Country code from the **Address field(this field is already getting updated by using JS inside web2lead form generated by OOTB feature of Salesforce)**. However while I am trying to update the Country field with the below formulas getting different errors:

`VALUE(Address.country)`
I am getting this error

> Error: Field Address does not exist. Check spelling.
> TEXT(Address): Incorrect parameter type for function 'TEXT()'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, Picklist, received Location

Any help would be appreciated in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reference the `Address` field on `Lead` in formula fields.

However, you can reference the `Country` field. In your formula, replace `Address.Country` with `Country`. (You won't need to wrap it in `TEXT` or `VALUE`)

Given that you can just reference the `Country` field directly, you don't need a formula field.

Comment: How are you creating this formula field? I have tested this myself and it works fine. The formula field is on Lead and is of type Text and the formula is `Country`

Comment: I was wrong..yes it's working ..you are amazing and that's why I MARKED YOUR ANSWER AS THE CORRECT ONE. THANKS A LOT AS IT HELPED ME A LOT. FYI I TRIED TO EDIT MY COMMENT GIVEN ABOVE ON TOP OF YOUR ANSWER BUT COULD NOT(NOT SURE WHY). PLEASE DON'T MIND. HOPE TO GET IN TOUCH WITH YOU AGAIN. APPRECIATE YOUR HELP A LOT. THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: ANY IDEA HOW TO UPDATE THE LEAD SOURCE FIELD TO 'WEB' WHILE CAPTURING THE LEAD INFO VIA WEB2LEAD FORM?

Comment: No sorry. Ask a new question and see if someone else knows